# Change where a Page is displayed in the URL

Tags: wagtail

I have setup my website whereby the main parental/tree structure is `Home > Shop > Category > Product"` with `>` denoting *parent of*.

This works fine, however when accessing  a `Product(Page)` the url is automatically (and correctly) configured at `/shop/test-category/test-product` by Wagtail.

I would like to change it so that the product is actually displayed as being at the root level (even though it isn't). So if a user accesses Test Product it would be at `/test-product/`.

Looking through the docs, the `RoutablePageMixin` seems like it might do the trick but I have no idea how to go about implementing it. Any ideas?

Comment: I put an answer below, but wanted to suggest a different approach, why not put all products directly under the `/shop/` page. Then product's URL will stay the same and be something like `/shop/test-product/`. Finally, you can add a field for `Category` to each `ProductPage` and use `RoutablePageMixin` on your `ShopPage` for things like `shop/category/.../`. URLs will be slightly longer but it makes for a more logical and flexible URL structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will make the product available at both URLS:

- `/shop/test-category/test-product/`
- `/test-product/`

**Approach:**

You are correct that you will need to use [`RoutablePageMixin`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html), be sure to install it in your installed_apps as per the instructions before importing.

The example below adds `RoutablePageMixin` to your `HomePage`, as this is the page that will be located at the root `/` URL. We do a regex check and match for a single slug before a trailing `/`.

Then we see if we can find a `ProductPage` with that slug, and serve (or redirect) to that page. Finally, if there is no match, we call the home_page's `serve` method with the current request to handle anything else. This may be an incorrect URL or a correct sub-page URL.

**Caveats:**

- If you have a sub-page at the same slug as a product page, the sub-page will never load, there are no smarts in this code to work around that. You could put some logic in the validation of product names and sub-page names if this becomes an issue in the future.
- This does not consider SEO issues, search engines will treat these as different pages and hence  you may want to think about declaring your [canonical URL](https://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps) in your meta tags.
- This does not redirect back from `/shop/test-category/test-product/` to `/test-product/` - that can be done by overriding the `serve` method on your `ProductPage` and redirecting to something like `home_page.url + '/' + self.slug`.

**Example Code:**

```
# models.py - assuming all your models are in one file
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import redirect  # only needed if redirecting

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage.models import RoutablePageMixin, route
from wagtail.core.models import Page


class ProductPage(Page):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('price')
    ]


class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):

    @route(r'^(?P<product_slug>[\w-]+)/$')
    def default_view(self, request, product_slug=None):
        """Route will match any `my-product-slug/` after homepage route."""
        product_page = Page.objects.exact_type(ProductPage).filter(slug=product_slug).first()
        if product_page:
            # option 1 - redirect to the product's normal URL (non-permanent redirect)
            # return redirect(product_page.specific.url)
            # option 2 - render the product page at this URL (no redirect)
            return product_page.specific.serve(request)
        else:
            # process to normal handling of request so correct sub-pages work
            return self.serve(request)
```